# Need help animating an image follow a circular path in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I'm working on a university project where I have to recreate the game of musical chairs, I'm at the part of animating the kids going in a circle around chairs. I have been trying to make a test with a rectangle following a circular path.
The problem is that I have an HBox with a tools bar that the mini game will need for later and the rectangle with the path in an stackpane, this two things are in a VBox that basically is the root. But the rectangle does the animation in the bottom right corner of the window and I would like to make it at the center of the stackpane. Any help would be apreciated. Here is the code:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javafxapplication4;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import javafx.animation.PathTransition;
import javafx.animation.PathTransition.OrientationType;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.CornerRadii;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.ArcTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.ClosePath;
import javafx.scene.shape.MoveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.Path;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import logica.CircularPane;

/**
 *
 * @author Franklin
 */
public class JavaFXApplication4 extends Application {
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws FileNotFoundException {
        VBox boxmaster=new VBox();
        
        StackPane stackpane=new StackPane();
        
        HBox tools=new HBox(); tools.setPrefHeight(70);
        
        
        //Botones y tool bar
        
        //start
        
        Button start=new Button();
        start.setPadding(new Insets(-1,-1,-1,-1));
        start.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        tools.getChildren().add(start);
        
        //Cambio de dirección
        HBox botones=new HBox(); botones.setSpacing(5);
        botones.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
        //izquierda
        
        Button left=new Button();
        left.setPadding(new Insets(-1,-1,-1,-1));
        left.setStyle("-fx-background-radius: 5em; " +
                "-fx-min-width: 50px; " +
                "-fx-min-height: 50px; " +
                "-fx-max-width: 50px; " +
                "-fx-max-height: 50px;");
        botones.getChildren().add(left);
        
        //derecha
        
        Button right=new Button();
        right.setPadding(new Insets(-1,-1,-1,-1));
        right.setStyle("-fx-background-radius: 5em; " +
                "-fx-min-width: 50px; " +
                "-fx-min-height: 50px; " +
                "-fx-max-width: 50px; " +
                "-fx-max-height: 50px;");
        botones.getChildren().add(right);
        
        //Pause
        
        Button pause=new Button();
        pause.setPadding(new Insets(-1,-1,-1,-1));
        pause.setStyle("-fx-background-radius: 5em; " +
                "-fx-min-width: 50px; " +
                "-fx-min-height: 50px; " +
                "-fx-max-width: 50px; " +
                "-fx-max-height: 50px;");
        botones.getChildren().add(pause);
        
        //Salir
        Button exit=new Button(); 
        exit.setStyle("-fx-background-radius: 5em; " +
                "-fx-min-width: 55px; " +
                "-fx-min-height: 55px; " +
                "-fx-max-width: 55px; " +
                "-fx-max-height: 55px;");
        exit.setVisible(false);
        botones.getChildren().add(exit);
        
        HBox.setHgrow(botones, Priority.ALWAYS);
        HBox.setMargin(start, new Insets(14,0,0,40));
        
        tools.getChildren().add(botones);
        tools.setPadding(new Insets(2));
        
        boxmaster.getChildren().add(tools);
        
        //Juego como tal
        Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(20, 20);
        rect2.setArcHeight(10);
        rect2.setArcWidth(10);
        rect2.setFill(Color.GREEN);
        stackpane.getChildren().add(rect2);
        
        Path path2 = createEllipsePath(0, 0, 150, 150, 0);
        stackpane.getChildren().add(path2);
        
        PathTransition pathCircle=new PathTransition();
        pathCircle.setDuration(Duration.seconds(2));
        pathCircle.setPath(path2);
        pathCircle.setNode(rect2);
        pathCircle.setOrientation(OrientationType.ORTHOGONAL_TO_TANGENT);
        pathCircle.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        pathCircle.setAutoReverse(false);
        
        stackpane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        boxmaster.getChildren().add(stackpane);
        VBox.setVgrow(stackpane, Priority.ALWAYS);
        Scene scene=new Scene(boxmaster,1080,720);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();
        pathCircle.play();
    }
    
    private Path createEllipsePath(double centerX, double centerY, double radiusX, double radiusY, double rotate)
    {
        ArcTo arcTo = new ArcTo();
        arcTo.setX(centerX - radiusX + 1); // to simulate a full 360 degree celcius circle.
        arcTo.setY(centerY - radiusY);
        arcTo.setSweepFlag(false);
        arcTo.setLargeArcFlag(true);
        arcTo.setRadiusX(radiusX);
        arcTo.setRadiusY(radiusY);
        arcTo.setXAxisRotation(rotate);

        Path path = new Path();
        path.getElements().addAll(
                new MoveTo(centerX - radiusX, centerY - radiusY),
                arcTo,
                new ClosePath()); // close 1 px gap.
        path.setStroke(Color.DODGERBLUE);
        path.getStrokeDashArray().setAll(5d, 5d);
        return path;
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
}
```

NOTES= The createEllipsePath code is what I found after digging on how to create a circular path.
The buttons do not have text, because originally they have a graphic.

Comment: What about, instead of using VBox for boxMaster use a BorderPane? Also, I think you're going to have to fix the size of your stack pane so the layout knows to give it room. Then your rectangle you'll need to give it coordinates relative to where it should be in the stack pane, so if you want it centered then you need to calculate the center.

Comment: Thats a great idea, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert in JavaFX. I just played around with your code and I got it to do what I think (and hope) you want it to do. I added an extra `Path`. The first `Path` draws the circle and the second `Path` is assigned to the `PathTransition`. I then played around with the coordinates of the second `Path` until I got the green rectangle to move around the circle that is the first path.

Note that I removed unused imports from your code and added a different letter to each of your `Button`s just so I could see where they appear in the `Scene`.

Here is the code.

```java
public class JavaFXApplication4 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) { //throws FileNotFoundException {
        VBox boxmaster = new VBox();
        StackPane stackpane = new StackPane();
        HBox tools = new HBox();
        tools.setPrefHeight(70);

        //Botones y tool bar

        //start

        Button start = new Button("S");
        start.setPadding(new Insets(-1,-1,-1,-1));
        start.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        tools.getChildren().add(start);

        //Cambio de dirección
        HBox botones = new HBox();
        botones.setSpacing(5);
        botones.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
        //izquierda
        
        Button left = new Button("L");
        left.setPadding(new Insets(-1,-1,-1,-1));
        left.setStyle("-fx-background-radius: 5em; " +
                      "-fx-min-width: 50px; " +
                      "-fx-min-height: 50px; " +
                      "-fx-max-width: 50px; " +
                      "-fx-max-height: 50px;");
        botones.getChildren().add(left);
        
        //derecha
        
        Button right = new Button("R");
        right.setPadding(new Insets(-1,-1,-1,-1));
        right.setStyle("-fx-background-radius: 5em; " +
                       "-fx-min-width: 50px; " +
                       "-fx-min-height: 50px; " +
                       "-fx-max-width: 50px; " +
                       "-fx-max-height: 50px;");
        botones.getChildren().add(right);
        
        //Pause
        
        Button pause = new Button("P");
        pause.setPadding(new Insets(-1,-1,-1,-1));
        pause.setStyle("-fx-background-radius: 5em; " +
                       "-fx-min-width: 50px; " +
                       "-fx-min-height: 50px; " +
                       "-fx-max-width: 50px; " +
                       "-fx-max-height: 50px;");
        botones.getChildren().add(pause);
        
        //Salir
        Button exit = new Button("E");
        exit.setStyle("-fx-background-radius: 5em; " +
                      "-fx-min-width: 55px; " +
                      "-fx-min-height: 55px; " +
                      "-fx-max-width: 55px; " +
                      "-fx-max-height: 55px;");
        exit.setVisible(false);
        botones.getChildren().add(exit);
        
        HBox.setHgrow(botones, Priority.ALWAYS);
        HBox.setMargin(start, new Insets(14, 0, 0, 40));
        
        tools.getChildren().add(botones);
        tools.setPadding(new Insets(2));
        
        boxmaster.getChildren().add(tools);
        
        //Juego como tal
        Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(20, 20);
        rect2.setArcHeight(10);
        rect2.setArcWidth(10);
        rect2.setFill(Color.GREEN);
        stackpane.getChildren().add(rect2);
        
        Path path2 = createEllipsePath(166, 10, 160, 160, 0);  // changed this line.
        Path path1 = createEllipsePath(0, 0, 150, 150, 0);  // added this line.
        stackpane.getChildren().add(path1);
        
        PathTransition pathCircle = new PathTransition();
        pathCircle.setDuration(Duration.seconds(2));
        pathCircle.setPath(path2);
        pathCircle.setNode(rect2);
        pathCircle.setOrientation(OrientationType.ORTHOGONAL_TO_TANGENT);
        pathCircle.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        pathCircle.setAutoReverse(false);
        
        stackpane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        boxmaster.getChildren().add(stackpane);
        VBox.setVgrow(stackpane, Priority.ALWAYS);
        Scene scene=new Scene(boxmaster,1080,720);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();
        pathCircle.play();
    }
    
    private Path createEllipsePath(double centerX, double centerY, double radiusX, double radiusY, double rotate)
    {
        ArcTo arcTo = new ArcTo();
        arcTo.setX(centerX - radiusX + 1); // to simulate a full 360 degree celcius circle.
        arcTo.setY(centerY - radiusY);
        arcTo.setSweepFlag(false);
        arcTo.setLargeArcFlag(true);
        arcTo.setRadiusX(radiusX);
        arcTo.setRadiusY(radiusY);
        arcTo.setXAxisRotation(rotate);

        Path path = new Path();
        path.getElements().addAll(
                new MoveTo(centerX - radiusX, centerY - radiusY),
                arcTo,
                new ClosePath()); // close 1 px gap.
        path.setStroke(Color.DODGERBLUE);
        path.getStrokeDashArray().setAll(5d, 5d);
        return path;
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution!